# How to define a template of template class

Tags: c++, templates, subclass

I' ve got a template class :

```
template <class T>
class A 
{
 ...
 protected:
  T m_value;
}
```

And i would like te make a template using this class for vectors:

```
template <class T>
class B:public A<std::vector<T>> //no need of space between >> (c++11)
{
 void testSize()
 {
    if(m_value.size() > ...)
    {
        ...
    }
 }
}
```

The compiler complain about : error: 'm_value' was not declared in this scope

is there a way i can do this or have i to recode this function for each std::vector type using directly the A class?

Thanks,

Edit:

I've tryed this:

```
template <class T>
class B:public A<std::vector<T>> //no need of space between >> (c++11)
{
 void testSize()
 {
    if(m_value.size() > ...)
    {
        ...
    }
 }

 std::vector<T> m_value;
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain anymore but does the m_value called in class A function's refer to m_value of class B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, `m_value` is a dependent name.
Just do this to correctly refer it from within `B`:

```
this->m_value.size()
```

That is, turn your `if` statement to:

```
if(this->m_value.size() > ...)
```

---

The code in the edit section is wrong instead. Class `B` and class `A` will refer respectively to their own copy of `m_value`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple that i'm ashamed!